# Mostrar solo el ID del div que acabo de presionar

Tags: javascript, jquery

Necesito mostrar constantemente el **ID** del `div` que presione, esto lo hago usando la función `setInterval` de `JavaScript`, el problema empieza cuando presiono otro `div`, me gustaría que ahora mostrara el **ID** del nuevo `div` que presione, pero en lugar de eso muestra los dos, y si vuelvo a presionar el primer `div`, muestra su **ID** dos veces, ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que al presionar un nuevo `div` deje de mostrar el **ID** del anterior? Hasta ahora tengo mi código así:

```js
$(".DivSecundario").click(function() {
  var ID = this.id;
  setInterval(ImprimirID, 1500, ID);
});

function ImprimirID(ID) {
  console.log(ID);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="DivPrincipal">
  <div class="DivSecundario" id="1">
    Sub div 1
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="DivSecundario" id="2">
    Sub div 2
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Necesitas crear una variable con el intervalo y usar `clearInterval()` cada vez que presionas los divs asi:

```js
var interval = null;

$(".DivSecundario").click(function(){
      if(interval) {
        clearInterval(interval);
      }
      var ID=this.id;
      interval = setInterval(ImprimirID,1500,ID);
    });

    function ImprimirID(ID){
      console.log(ID);
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="DivPrincipal">
      <div class="DivSecundario" id="1">
        Sub div 1
      </div>
      <br>
      <div class="DivSecundario" id="2">
        Sub div 2
      </div>
    </div>
```